# how to get HTTP status in variable with file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have script :

```
<?php
  $url = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
  if(HTTP_STATUS == "404")
   {
     echo "Status : 404";
   }
 ?>
```

how to variable in IF so i can track `http status`?
 
 So if HTTP Status was `404` it will `echo "Status : 404"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saty's answer is write, also i would like to suggest using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), after `curl_exec`, you can get all the information using [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Example from the same link:

```
<?php
// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

 echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
 echo 'HTTP STATUS CODE: ' . $info['http_code'];
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The result can be returned fetched from curl_exec using [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) by settings `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`.

Example:

```
<?php
// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

 echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
 echo 'HTTP STATUS CODE: ' . $info['http_code'];
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);

// use $result
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP response can be found in the variable [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) after calling `file_get_contents`:

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com");
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_headers()`

```
$file = 'http://www.example.com';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    echo "Status : 404";
}
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: This will send a HEAD request to the URI. Although this might get you a 404 error if the resource didn't exist it would require two requests in a normal case one `get_headers()` to test and one `file_get_content()` to get the actual content. There might be a use case for it, though.